# bash: Why am I getting syntax error near unexpected token `}'?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very simple script number_guess.sh which is running inside a docker container and using vs-code with utf-8 character encoding in settings without automatically changing encoding based on file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello!";

HELLO () {
  # function budy
}
```

This keeps generating the following error:

```
./number_guess.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./number_guess.sh: line 7: `}'
```

I have tried adding and removing spaces but to no avail. I have also tried to explicitly save file with encoding utf-8 using the editor but also to no avail.

I don't know what is causing the issue and I feel lost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998558/empty-function-in-bash

Comment: Your function may need a colon or a semicolon at least.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307615/why-cannot-i-define-an-empty-function-in-shell holds an explanation for the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function body cannot be empty:

```
HELLO() {
  echo "hello!"
}
```

This will work

Comment: Omg, you have no idea how long debugging this took me. I tried that before didn't work, rebuild and re-did everything and then left the comment assuming it counted as function body. Thanks a lot, this solved my issue!